# Historical motivation for Hilbert's Third problem

Tags: geometry, math-history

What was the historical motivation for Hilbert's third problem? Why did Hilbert feel it was worthy of including on his published list?

**Hilbert's Third problem:**
Say that two polyhedra are *scissors congruent* if one can be cut up into finitely many polyhedra, each piece rotated/translated and then reassembled into the other polyhedron. Hilbert asked whether or not the unit cube and the regular tetrahedron of unit volume were scissors congruent.

Hilbert's student Dehn answered "no," providing an invariant (now known as the Dehn invariant) which remained unchanged under scissors congruence, but yielded different values for the cube and the regular tetrahedron.

Comment: I asked David about it at the time. He told me this long story involving a beer stein, a talking donkey and a panda. Still not sure.

Comment: My guess (but a guess only!) is that Hilbert was motivated by axiomatization of Euclidean geometry, where the notion of area and volume is in fact quite tricky. One would like to define them rigorously in elementary terms, without resorting to the general measure/integration theory.

Comment: Any reason to doubt what [wikipedia writes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_third_problem#History_and_motivation)?

Comment: No, just missed that. Thanks!